# precision error in nth root of a number in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, floating-accuracy

I know from previous threads on this topic that using float arithmetic causes precision anomalies. But Interestingly I observed that the same function is behaving in two different ways.
Using COUT output is **4** but if I am saving the result into a variable, then result is **3**!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#define mod 1000000007
long long int fastPower(long long int a, int n){
    long long int res = 1;
    while (n) {
            if (n & 1) res = (res * a) % mod;
            n >>= 1; a = (a * a) % mod;
    }
    return res;
}
int main() {
    int j = 3;
    cout << pow(64, (double)1.0/(double)j) << endl; // Outputs 4
    int root = pow(64, (double)1.0/(double)j);
    cout << root << endl;                           // Outputs 3
    /* As said by "pts", i tried including this condition in my code but including this line in my code resulted in TimeLimitExceeded(TLE). */
    if (fastPower(root+1,j) <= 64) root++;
    cout << root << endl;                           // Outputs 4 :)
    return 0;
}
```

[Code output on Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/XcAo8V)
Now, how can we avoid such errors in a programing contest.
I do not want to use 'round' function because I need only integer value of root. i.e
63<sup>(1/6)</sup> = 1, 20<sup>(1/2)</sup> = 4, etc... 
How should I modify my code so that correct result is stored in the root variable.

Comment: Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: All those `(double)`s lead me to believe that you don't know the rules of C++ literals, operators and type promotions.

Comment: @KerrekSB yes they always confuse me, so i end up putting it everywhere!

Comment: @AtulVaibhav: Don't program by guessing or throwing syntax at a keyboard until something sticks. *Learn*, and be deliberate.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no single-line answer in C and C++ for getting the `a`th root of `b` rounded down.

As a quick workaround, you can do something like:

```
int root(int a, int b) {
  return floor(pow(b, 1.0 / a) + 0.001);
}
```

This doesn't work for every value, but by adjusting the constant (`0.001`), you may get lucky and it would work for the test input.

As a workaround, use `pow` as you use it already, and if it returns `r`, then try `r - 1`, `r` and `r + 1` by multiplying it back (using fast exponentiation of integers). This will work most of the time.

If you need a solution which works 100% of the time, then don't use floating point numbers. Use for example binary search with exponentiation. There are faster algorithms (such as Newton iteration), but if you use them on integers then you need to write custom logic to find the exact solution as soon as they stop converging.

Comment: If you have already tried something, it makes sense to copy-paste the corresponding code to your question, to give others a chance to help you find out what's wrong with that code.

Comment: TimeLimitExceeded most probably indicates another, unrelated bug in your code. You are still not showing enough code to get useful help on why you got the TimeLimitExceeded. For example, you are not showing the implementation of your fastPower function.

Comment: actually it is related to a live contest so I cannot post my complete code. I will do that once the contest gets over.

Answer (score 2):

pow returns double. When cout is used, it is rounded(thus, it is 4). When you cast it to int, it just truncates fractional part. Pow returns something like 4 - eps(because of precision issues). When it is just truncated, it is equal to 3.
Dirty hack useful in programming contests: `int root = (int)(pow(...) + 1e-7)`

Comment: I added possible solution to my answer.

Comment: Or use the round function, `(int)round(pow(..,..))`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your program:

1. The `pow(int, int)` overload is no longer available.  To avoid this problem, cast the first parameter to `double`, `float`, or `long double`.
2. Also, command of `cout` is rounding off your answer in upper roof (3.something into 4) and saving your data is removing all the decimal part and is accepting only integer part.