# Getting wrong value for same mathematical operation in c?

Tags: c, math

I am trying to calculate the greatest integer less than or equal to the *i*th root of a positive integer. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t>0)
    {
        long long n,q,a,b,res=0,den,x,y,z;
        int w;
        scanf("%lld",&n);

        long *arr = (long*) malloc(n*sizeof(long));
        scanf("%lld",&q);
        long *qrr = (long*) malloc(q*sizeof(long));
        for(x=0;x<n;x++)
        {
            scanf("%ld",&arr[x]);
        }
        for(y=0;y<q;y++)
        {
            scanf("%ld",&qrr[y]);
        }
        for(z=0;z<q;z++)
        {
            res = 0;
            for(w=1;w<=n;w++)
            {
                printf("%ld\n",qrr[z]);
                printf("%lld\n",(long long)(pow(qrr[z],1.0/(3))));
                res += ((long long)(pow(qrr[z],1.0/(w)))*arr[w-1]);
            }
            printf("%lld\n",res%1000000007);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my input

```
1
3 2
4 5 6
8 30
```

Answer with input `130` is correct but with `8` its wrong.
My output is

```
8
1
8
1
8
1
48
30
3
30
3
30
3
163
```

Comment: `new` is not C, use `malloc`

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is inexact. Your calculation is subject to rounding error.

Comment: `pow` works with floating-point numbers, the result of your cubic root will be inexact. (The `1.0/3` is already inexact.) That doesn't explain, why the two outputs differ if `qrr[z] == 8`, though.

Comment: I get `2` on both. Check that `qrr[z]` is indeed `8`; I've got the feeling that it's not.

Comment: I have checked qrr[z] many 3 times.I will try again.

Comment: While doing that, [See it live](http://ideone.com/Z6fZ9l). I highly suspect your error is in your indexing of `qrr`. You never show what `z` is, how you set it, etc.

Comment: @user3714283 Post your whole source. how to tell like `qrr[z] == 8`? means what is `z`?

Comment: Shall we just assume `using namespace std;` is a typo? Or are you really building this with a C++ compiler? And `printf("%ld\n",res%1000000007);` will not do what you want, you're sending a `long long` to a `%ld` (aka. `long`) format specification. That just plain won't work.

Comment: yes, i am building this with c++ compiler.

Comment: I changed ld to lld but still getting error.

Comment: it gets more ambiguous now !! 
what is meant by  _first line_ and _second line_ because i can see that you printing a bunch of data ?!!

Comment: I copied your code from ideone to code blocks compiler and got different values. @WhozCraig

Comment: Care to share what those "different values" *were* ?

Comment: I was printing all that data just to see if my output is correct.

Comment: 1 with qrr[z] and 2 with 8

Comment: Forgive me, but I simply can't believe it. What *platform* is this on? And again, post your **exact** input and **exact** output for your posted question (not that it matters at this point if the trivial sample I linked doesn't even work on your rig).

Comment: Window 7 64 bit, intel i3 processor and code blocks 12.11

Comment: Should i post the code from your IDEONE and my exact input and output for that code.Thank you very much for being so patient @WhozCraig.

Comment: No, *again*, for your *posted question*, the *exact* input and output you're providing, amended *to the question* please.

Comment: And you may find [your code on IDEone](http://ideone.com/FxHpFC) interesting. Btw, Codeblocks isn't a compiler; its an IDE. What *compiler* are you using?

Comment: minw gcc is the compiler then.

Comment: [See your code live, updated with your input](http://ideone.com/FxHpFC). I have no idea what the problem is on your platform. The only thing I changed in the code was actually enforcing an exit condition with `t` (your code spun in an infinite loop) and the `res` output format flag changed to `%lld`.

Comment: Yes both answers are correct on IDEone. Actually, t was number of test cases.Let me copy that code again and try on my system.

Comment: My faith in MinGW has hereby reached an all-time low. My results on my Mac (clang++ 3.4) are the same as those on IDEOne.

Comment: Stil same problem.Should i try a different IDE or a window reinstall.

Comment: Personally, I'd download Visual Studio Express 2013 (its free) and give that a shot. (I can't believe I just said that, btw). Regardless, *this should work*. There are plenty of people out there using MinGW with success (obviously). I may just be too tired to see the obvious. Sorry about that. There are some damn-sharp people on this site. Maybe someone else can see it. In the meantime, continue to litter your code with debug `printf()` statements, properly formatted. It couldn't hurt to be sure stuff is what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks i will keep trying to know what's wrong and download Visual studio express 2013 too.

Comment: Also, check [your posted code again on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/FxHpFC). I updated it to ensure `qrr[z]` was what we think it is. It looks right on that site (of course).

Comment: Yes every value is what i thought it is.I am trying it on visual studio now.I will comment if the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you i got correct answer using Visual Studio.Thank you very much. @WhozCraig

Comment: Wow. I'm the first person to stand up and say observed-behavior is not defined-behavior, but either everyone else got lucky, or MinGW is doing something wrong. It may be worth filing a bug (or there may already be one, for that matter). Glad you're up and running. How bizarre. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This was recently observed in another question, [precision error in nth root of a number in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24110028/3088138), (and not so recently in [code blocks power function is not working in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15050997/3088138)) the power function of code-blocks resp. libm of mingw is sub-optimal in terms of accuracy. Use `round` before converting to (long long) integer to account for the limited accuracy of `exp(y*ln(x))` as implementation for `pow(x,y)`.

```
(long long int)round(pow(x,y))
```

---

As this solves only half the problem, since the desired result is `floor(pow(x,1.0/k))`, and the problem occurs if x is an exact power n^k, where the result should be n and not, due to accuracy problems, n-1, ... modify the input so that you compute

```
floor(pow(x+0.5, 1.0/k))
```

Then, 63.5 is still noticeably smaller than 64 so that `floor(pow(63.5,1.0/3))=3`, but 64.5 is now noticeably larger than 64, so that also `pow(64.5,1.0/3)` will be robustly larger than 4 (and far out of range of 5).

---

Of course, converting to integer applies floor implicitly, so no need to use this function in the code.

Answer (score -1):

you need to allocate memory for your variable

```
long *qrr;

qrr = (long*) malloc(q*sizeof(long));
```

**EDIT** (additional guess)

try both:

`pow(qrr[z], 0.33);`
`pow(qrr[z], 1/3);`

i guess something is happening here, your `1/3` is being interpretted as `0`

Comment: which variable (long long)(pow(8,1.0/(3))) should i first put it in a variable

Comment: @user3714283 your long array qrr

Comment: Still the answers are not matching.

Comment: what is `z` in your `qrr[z]` ?

Comment: `printf("%ld\n",qrr[z]);` just before you do powers and let'us know how much it is pls

Comment: the line: pow(qrr[z], 1/3);  is performing a integer divide of 1/3. this can be corrected to pow(qrr[z], 1.0/3.0);